# my wordpress website takes long time to load how to reduce it?

Tags: jquery, css, image, wordpress

I am running a wordpress website on local language its take more than 20 seconds to load, I removed un-wanted scripts and everything from the header but still its take time to load.

here is the url
http://www.thefirstdrive.com

Comment: Took only a few seconds to load on my machine... are you certain it is not your internet connection?

Comment: I think here you attached lot of images. you reduced the size of your image and attach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the **Network Tab** in **Web-inspector**, you can find the time each resource took to load

[image: Inspector]

In your case, the loading of **the above image** is taking the most time. You could try to compress it somehow. It is `1.66 MB` in size, which is the bottle-neck in your case.